# Angular 5 ngx-modialog error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-modialog/plugins/vex'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

Using the Angular 5 CLI, I add the module ngx-modialog:

`npm install --save ngx-modialog`

I add it to the `app.module.ts`:

```
import { VexModalModule } from "ngx-modialog/plugins/vex";
import { ModalModule } from "ngx-modialog";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // module imports
        BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, RouterModule,
        ModalModule.forRoot(), VexModalModule
    ],
    ...
})
```

I try to use DialogPreset in a class (`modal-context.ts`):

```
import { DialogPreset } from "ngx-modialog/plugins/vex";

export class ModalContext extends DialogPreset {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.className = 'plain';
        this.isBlocking = false;
    }
}
```

When I try `ng serve` I get the following in my modal-context.ts:

`error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-modialog/plugins/vex'.`

Why is Angular CLI not finding the `ngx-modialog/plugins/vex`?

```
> ls node_modules/ngx-modialog/
bundle  package.json  plugins  src

> ls node_modules/ngx-modialog/plugins
bootstrap  js-native  vex

> ls node_modules/ngx-modialog/plugins/vex
bundle  package.json  src
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this issue when using TypeScript 2.5.3. Downgrading to 2.5.2 resolved it for me.

Steps to downgrade TypeScript:

1. Open *package.json*
2. Locate `devDependencies` and change TypeScript version `"typescript": "2.5.2"`
3. Run `npm install`